# reveal.js - possible to rebind keys on specific slides?

Tags: javascript, reveal.js

I'm using reveal.js to setup a presentation and wanted to know if it was possible to rebind the keyboard actions once I hit a certain slide.

I have an idea in my head of how it would work, but in practice it just doesn't.

I've just tried to drop reveal.configure between the section tags but it doesn't work that way I guess - is there another method I can use?

```
<section>
    <script>
        Reveal.configure({
            39: slide( 8 ) // bind right arrow to jump to slide 8
        })
    <script>
<section>
```